# How do you write a function that can utilize sumif across an array?

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

Is there a way to write a single function to do the following in excel/sheets?

1. Sum `measure_a` and `measure_b` by `date`
2. Filter by `employee` and the new `sum_measure_a >= 30`
3. Calculate the mean for all of the new `sum_measure_b`

Here is an example...

| employee | date | measure_a | measure_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 2/1 | 10 | 50 |
| AA | 2/1 | 10 | 50 |
| AA | 2/1 | 20 | 80 |
| AA | 2/2 | 10 | 40 |
| AA | 2/2 | 10 | 50 |
| AA | 2/3 | 20 | 80 |
| AA | 2/3 | 20 | 90 |
| BB | 2/1 | 30 | 100 |

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

So the expected output would be a function that

1. Would filter all `employee` values by lookup (here AA)
2. Would calculate the sum of `measure_a` for each date
3. Would identify 2/1 and 2/3 as the dates required (based on the sum of `measure_a` >= 30)
4. Would sum the total for each `measure_b` for each of those day (here 2/1 = 180 and 2/3 = 170)
5. And finally finds the mean for the daily totals. So final answer is 175 for AA.

| employee | mean_measure_b |
| --- | --- |
| AA | 175 |
| BB | 100 |

Comment: As you can see by the answers provided Excel and google sheets are far from the same. Don't tag both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try:

```
=QUERY(QUERY({A2:D},"Select Col1, Col2, SUM(Col3), SUM(Col4) WHERE Col1<>'' GROUP BY Col1, Col2"),"Select Col1, AVG(Col4) Where Col3>=30 GROUP BY Col1 LABEL AVG(Col4)'' ")
```

- 

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Excel this could be done using Microsoft 365:

```
=LET(data,  A2:D9,
     empl,  INDEX(data,,1),
     date,  INDEX(data,,2),
     m_A,   INDEX(data,,3),
     m_B,   INDEX(data,,4),
     e_d,   HSTACK(empl,date),
     u,     UNIQUE(e_d),
     u_1,   INDEX(u,,1),
     u_2,   INDEX(u,,2),
     mm_cond,(TRANSPOSE(empl)=u_1)*(TRANSPOSE(date)=u_2),
     mm_A,  MMULT(mm_cond,m_A),
     mm_B,  MMULT(mm_cond,m_B), 
             
     filtered, FILTER(HSTACK(u_1,mm_B),mm_A>=30),
     Unq,      UNIQUE(INDEX(filtered,,1)),
     mm_cond_B,--(TRANSPOSE(INDEX(filtered,,1))=Unq),         
     sum_B,    MMULT(mm_cond_B,INDEX(filtered,,2)),    
     count_B   MMULT(mm_cond_B,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(INDEX(filtered,,2)),,1,0)),
HSTACK(Unq,sum_B/count_B))
```

It first calculates the sum of measure a for each unique employee/date combination and the same for measure b.

Then it filters out the lines where the sum of measure a is smaller than 30.

Than it takes the average of the listed values for each employee.